# Android : Google map change color of driving route on cross

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2, polyline, driving-directions

As I have drawn an driving route direction on Google map from source to destination with red color poly-line. Now I want to change the color of the that poly-line from red to some other color(like blue) on follow of that route(I think how to animate the marker on map). How can I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check this tutorial:

http://javapapers.com/android/draw-path-on-google-maps-android-api/

```
polyLineOptions.color(Color.BLUE);
```

Find above line and change color as you want.